# how do i follow the url casperjs

Tags: javascript, forms, url, casperjs

here is my casperjs script below everything is working fine i just need help following a redirect

```
var casper = require('casper').create ({
    waitTimeout: 15000,
    stepTimeout: 15000,
    verbose: true,
    viewportSize: {
        width: 1280,
        height: 960
    },
    pageSettings: {
        "userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1262.0 Safari/537.10',
        "webSecurityEnabled": false,
        "ignoreSslErrors": true
    },
    onWaitTimeout: function() {
      // casper.capture('./out/wait-timeout:_' + TimeTidy() + '.png');
      // throw newItem Error stuff;
    },
    onStepTimeout: function() {
      // casper.capture('./out/step-timeout' + TimeTidy() + '.png');
      // throw newItem Error stuff;
    }
});

// Vars
var fs  = require('fs');
var url = 'https://www.bt.com/wifi/secure/index.do?s_cid=con_FURL_btwifi';

// Start
casper.start();

casper.thenOpen(url, function() {
    // this.echo(this.getTitle());
    casper.click("a[href='http://www.bt.com/wifi/secure/status.do']");
    this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
});

// Wait 2 sec then write to txt file
casper.wait(9000, function() {
    this.echo(this.getHTML());
    this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
});

// Executes
casper.run();
```

how can i visit the last

```
this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
```

and fill in a form if any one can help me on adding this function to my form i would be so happy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to truly understand what you want to do.

Capser should follow redirections, so nothing to do.

To fill the form just add a new step like this

```
casper.then(function () {
    casper.fill('form[name=LoginForm]', {
        'username':'YOURUSERNAME',
        'password':'YOURPASSWORD'
    }, true);
});
```

Comment: thanks for this comment i forgot to delete this qeustion the problems was solved thanks for your answer i will accept it as it is basically part of what i had to do